# async await in express call

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm learning async / await and trying to use it to fix a bug with the code where the mongoose query doesn't come back in time before the server sends data back to the client

when a username is queried, the code checks if the user is logged in if req.userId exists, queries it and sets a _self variable and later that data is sent back to the client

how do I only send the data back only after the mongoose query on the req.userId is done?

```
app.get('/:username', async function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.params.username })
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        .....
        let _self = null;

        if (req.userId != null) {
            User.findOne({ _id: req.userId}, function(err, self) {
                await _self = self.toObject();
            });
        }

        return res.status(200).send({user: _user, self: _self })
    })
})
```

I get a 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function' error

Comment: Your `findOne()` callback isnt an async function. Not that it helps as your `status()` call still happens before that callback gets called anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code

```js
app.get('/:username', async function(req, res) {
    try{
        var user = await User.findOne({ username: req.params.username })
        .....
        let _self = null;

        if (req.userId != null) {
            var self = await User.findOne({ _id: req.userId})
            _self = self.toObject()
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        throw err
    }
    return res.status(200).send({user: _user, self: _self })
})
```

Async / Await is used to resolve promises.
Instead of callback use await to resolve the promise, once it is resolved the return value of the async function is returned.

findOne is an aysnc function hence await should be used with findOne. toObject is a synchronous function hence there is no requirement to use await

Comment: it works partially, did you mean self = await User...? rather than await self =?

Comment: await self = User.findOne({ _id: req.userId})
        ^^^^^^^^^^

ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: I had made a Typo check it now

Comment: can you show me how to use it with this new code, please?

Comment: i have updated the code. Use try catch for error handling